# How to recommend an attribute value for optimum output

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, optimization

I have set of attributes A (continuous value),B,C and the result is X where X is an continues value. I have data set and I can train a model with that data. At certain point I have to determine the value of A attribute in order to take the optimum X value while other attributes are provided. So I have to recommend value for A attribute to take optimum X value. Can this problem be modeled using recommender systems. So how? If not, what is the correct way of modeling this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not so related to the recommender system field.

First of all, train a model with $A,B,C$ as inputs and $X$ as output. This is a standard task in machine learning called **regression**. Let call the learned model as $X=f(A,B,C)$.

An iterative way to find the value of $A$ that optimizes $X$ is to use the **gradient descent** algorithm. You start with a random initial value for $A$ and in each iteration, you add/subtract a small value to $A$ such that it makes a small improvement to X. To do that you should first choose a small positive value $\eta$ called the **learning rate**. In each iteration, do the following:

```
current_X = f(current_A,B,C)
new_A1 = current_A + η
new_X1 = f(new_A1,B,C)
new_A2 = current_A - η
new_X2 = f(new_A2,B,C)
if new_X1 is better than new_X2:
    current_A = new_A1
else:
    current_A = new_A2
```

This algorithm iteratively approaches the desired value of $A$ that makes $X$ optimum.